# Does test method have to be static

Tags: apex

I searched the related documents but didn't find any specific requirement for the testmethod to be static. But from my previous experience, they are always static, and that is logical. But is it a *must* thing for a testmethod to be static?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge they have to be static.

```
To define an Apex method as a 'test method', simply define the method as static and add the keyword testMethod.
```

Comment: I agree with Artur.  Although you are right, I cannot find anywhere it explicitly says that it HAS to be static, but it's my understanding that is the case, just cant find it documented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it must be defined as static. If you try to save a test class without a static test method, you get an error:

```
Only static top-level class methods can be test methods
```